# Check whether the current page is index or not in ZenCart

Tags: php, zen-cart

I'm using a ZenCart in my website, actually I want to customise the look of my site. I've done this for the index pages but not for the inner pages, because those same pages are using for the inner pages.

For example the banner image is on the index page and I don't want to see it in the inner pages. What is the correct way to put a check in the pages that whether it is index page of any other inner page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple

check below code

```
if($_GET['main_page']=='index' and !isset($_GET['cPath']))
{
// your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... i maked it working yesterday, But thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$current_page_base` variable - it's set and maintained by Zen Cart. I'm not sure if  `$_GET['main_page']` is ever overridden in Zen Cart code but it seems safer to not rely on it.